# Meaning of (x => x) in JavaScript arrow function using array.every() method

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

looking for an explanation on this line of code.  I understand arrow functions to a degree.  The purpose of this code snippet/challenge is; "Given any number of parameters, return true if none of the arguments are falsy."  I've seen the solution like this:

```
const nothingIsNothing = (...args) => args.every(x => x)
```

Examples of arguments and the expected results are:

```
nothingIsNothing(0, false, undefined, null) ➞ false

nothingIsNothing(33, "Hello",  true,  []) ➞ true

nothingIsNothing(true, false) ➞ false
```

I just don't understand how the section `(x => x)` evaluates to either truthy or falsy.  Can someone explain how this works?  I hope this makes sense lol.  Thanks!

Comment: To the right of `=>` is what is returned without `{}` on an Arrow function.

Comment: Do you understand fat arrow and implicit return? Do you understand truthy values?

Comment: I've always done this test for uniform truthiness: `arr.every(Boolean)`. I guess this identify function `x => x` is another option.

Comment: I do understand those concepts - I guess I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around why that particular piece of code `(x => x)` returns either a truthy or falsey value.  Outside of the .every() method, I would understand that with map(), for example, that `(x => x +2)` would add two to every element.  I also understand that if we had a snippet such as returning `x > 2`, that it would return true for all values that are greater than 2 and false for values less than 2.  I'm just not picking up why `(x => x)` is either truthy or falsey.

Comment: it's about what `.every` is doing "under the hood", which is that it is checking the return value of the callback for truthiness. maybe think of it as if `.every` internally is checking the return value of that function with `!!` or just `if (x)`

Comment: Thanks all - I think I get it now.  The implicit return is what was throwing me off, but after reading the comments, I see how that plays into the arrow function returning either a truthy or falsey value.  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, the PloyFill of every shows this nicely as demonstrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `.every`, if any of the return values from the callback are falsey, the `.every` evaluates to `false`, otherwise it evaluates to `true`. So `x => x` as a callback means: take every value in the array and return it immediately. If all are truthy, the whole `.every` evaluates to `true`, else `false`.

It's doing the same logic as this:

```
const nothingIsNothing = (...args) => {
  for (const arg of args) {
    if (!arg) return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

Or, implementing something similar to `.every` yourself:

```js
// don't do this in real code, this is just an example

Array.prototype.myEvery = function(callback) {
  for (const item of this) {
    if (!callback(item)) return false;
  }
  return true;
};

console.log([1, 2, 3].myEvery(x => x));
console.log([1, 2, 3, 0].myEvery(x => x));
```

Comment: OK, I think this is helping.  So basically the `(x => x) ` snippet is saying that the value of x will be returned immediately, and when that happens, it will be either evaluated as truthy or falsey at that point?  If all are truthy, the .every() method will evaluate to true, and if not, the .every() method will evaluate to false?

Answer (score 1):

Its a combinations of a couple of things

1. Javascript implicit `return` statement.

`getVal = a => a;`

is the same as

```
function getVal(a) { return a }
```

2. every web API method run until it encounters a `falsy` (not false) value. Below is a quote from MDN.

> The every method executes the provided callback function once for each
> element present in the array until it finds the one where callback
> returns a falsy value. If such an element is found, the every method
> immediately returns false. Otherwise, if callback returns a truthy
> value for all elements, every returns true.

Answer (score 1):

`param => param` is the same as `(param) => { return param }`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

These are all the falsy values in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

The documentation for the return value of `every` states the following:

> true if the callback function returns a truthy value for every array
> element. Otherwise, false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

So something like this will be false as not all elements are truthy

```js
const x = ['test', 0, null, -0].every(el => el);
console.log(x);
```

But something like this will return true as all elements are truthy values

```js
const x = ['test', 1, 'hi', 10].every(el => el);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) the `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a **`Boolean`** value i.e `true` if the callback function returns a [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/truthy) value for every array element. Otherwise, `false`.

`const nothingIsNothing = (...args) => args.every(x=>x)` can be expanded to:

```
const nothingIsNothing = (...args) => args.every(function(x){
if(x)
  return true
else 
  return false
})
```

Here is another version which will help you understand the shorthand better. The value x is typecasted to a boolean and true/false is returned.

```js
const nothingIsNothing = (...args) => args.every(Boolean)
console.log(nothingIsNothing(0, false, undefined, null))
console.log(nothingIsNothing(33, "Hello",  true,  []))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Array.prototpe.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) does the heavy lifting here.

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
> test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

The PolyFil following the ECMA-262, 5th specification, assuming Object and TypeError have their original values, and that callbackfn.call evaluates to the original value of Function.prototype.call, demonstrate the internal behavior nicely:

```js
Array.prototype.PolyFillEvery = function(callbackfn, thisArg) {
  'use strict';
  var T, k;

  if (this == null) {
    throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
  }

  // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this 
  //    value as the argument.
  var O = Object(this);

  // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal method
  //    of O with the argument "length".
  // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
  var len = O.length >>> 0;

  // 4. If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
  if (typeof callbackfn !== 'function' && Object.prototype.toString.call(callbackfn) !== '[object Function]') {
    throw new TypeError();
  }

  // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    T = thisArg;
  }

  // 6. Let k be 0.
  k = 0;

  // 7. Repeat, while k < len
  while (k < len) {

    var kValue;

    // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
    //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
    // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal 
    //    method of O with argument Pk.
    //   This step can be combined with c
    // c. If kPresent is true, then
    if (k in O) {
      var testResult;
      // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal method
      //    of O with argument Pk.
      kValue = O[k];

      // ii. Let testResult be the result of calling the Call internal method 
      // of callbackfn with T as the this value if T is not undefined 
      // else is the result of calling callbackfn 
      // and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
      if(T) testResult = callbackfn.call(T, kValue, k, O); 
      else testResult = callbackfn(kValue,k,O)

      // iii. If ToBoolean(testResult) is false, return false.
      if (!testResult) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    k++;
  }
  return true;
};

const arFalsey = [0, false, undefined, null];
const arTruthy = [33, "Hello",  true,  []];

console.log(arFalsey.PolyFillEvery(x=>x)); //false
console.log(arTruthy.PolyFillEvery(x=>x)); //true
console.log([true,false].PolyFillEvery(x=>x)); //false
```

The crucial part is if-clause in the inside of the loop:

```
// iii. If ToBoolean(testResult) is false, return false.
if (!testResult) {
  return false;
}
```

As soon as one of the elements is not tested truthy `false` is returned; the spread (`...`) expression is simply used to iterate the array and instead of a traditional function an arrow function `x => x` is used to feed (via return) each element as is to the test in the `every` function.